# Passing a Variable fillColor to Google Map

Tags: python, google-maps, flask

I am using Python and Flask to overlay a polygon on a Google map, with the bounds and colour of the polygon being passed in as variables.

My code draws simple square. I can pass the co-ordinates as variables fine

```
`var sq1 = [
new google.maps.LatLng({{ result [7] }}, {{ result [8] }}),
new google.maps.LatLng({{ result [7] }}, {{ result [10] }}),
new google.maps.LatLng({{ result [9] }}, {{ result [10] }}),
new google.maps.LatLng({{ result [9] }}, {{ result [8] }}),
new google.maps.LatLng({{ result [7] }}, {{ result [8] }}),
];
sq1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: sq1,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillOpacity: 1,
fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
});
```

But if I change

```
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
```

to

```
    fillColor: {{ result [12] }},
```

The it stops working. Result[12] returns #FFFFFF, I've also tried altering it to return '#FFFFFF' but to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When outputting values to be used for JavaScript, you need to make sure you escape your data property.

```
fillColor: {{ result[12] }},
```

will output

```
fillColor: #FFFFFF,
```

This isn't valid JavaScript. What you want it to output -- your first example had it -- is

```
fillColor: '#FFFFFF",
```

There are two ways you could accomplish this. The simplest way to do it is

```
fillColor: '{{ result[12] }}',
```

The other way to do this is a bit safer as it can be used for all variables being output to JavaScript. It is smart enough to put quotes around strings and treat numbers as such. It should also handle boolean values properly.

```
fillColor: {{ result[12]|tojson|safe }},
```

An example of this is provided in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-filters).